# Angular 4 - unable to set default value of dropdown

Tags: angular

I have created a Reactive form in Angular 4. It has a drop down field, values for which are fetched through a web service call.

In addition to the values returned by the web service, I want to display another option in the drop down, with some label like 'Please select a value' and have this selected by default.

My template looks like

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="property" class="col-xs-4">Description</label>
              <div class="col-xs-8">
                <select id="property" formControlName="property" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option *ngFor="let property of properties" [ngValue]="property">{{ property }}</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="'No Selection'" [selected]="selected">Please select a value </option>
                 </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

then in the component

```
this.myService.get("prop")
  .subscribe(
  (response: Response) => {
    let items: any[] = JSON.parse(response.text());
    for (let item of items) {
      let property = item.val;
      this.properties.push(property);
      this.myForm.setControl('property', new FormControl(property));
    }
  }

  )
```

This populates the drop down with all values returned from the service, along with an additional value 'Please select a value'.

However, the additional value is not selected by default. In fact, from all the values returned by the server, the last value is selected by default.

I have tried the standard HTML options like 'selected'. It seems that the 'No Selection' is selected by default but then gets over ridden by values from the server so the default value changes to one of the values returned by the server.

Comment: Seems it works for me https://plnkr.co/edit/VFQ6otOgEtEYKJm1xfpH?p=preview

Comment: are you using coreUI project for angualr4 ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by coreUI project? Can you please provide some more details?

Comment: Hi yurzui, that is precisely the problem that I am facing. Thanks for creating the plnkr. When the page loads 'Please select a value' is selected in the dropdown. However, as soon as the timeout resolves 'Prop3' gets selected. If you don't get this behavior in your browser try increasing the timeout to say 5 secs. I would like 'Please select a value' to be selected even after timeout resolves.